# How can I preserve the dates of the successive versions while importing a project into Git?

Tags: git, date

I have a folder on my desktop with the following contents:

```
SABS/
|-SABS v0.1b/
  |-sabs.sh
|-SABS v0.2b/
  |-sabs.sh
|-SABS v0.3b/
  |-sabs.sh
|-SABS v0.4b/
  |-sabs.sh
|-SABS v0.5b/
  |-sabs.sh
```

Inside each of these folders is a script file. Each script file has a different date associated with them.

I started working on this script before realizing I could use Git.

My question is: is it possible to keep the history and the times when the files were created using Git and import them? That way when you look at `sabsv0.1` it will show the date in which it was created, but not the date in which it was imported to Git.

Comment: Is there a reason why the file creation date is important?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep track of dates because they go years back. I would like to know at what point in time a certain change was made.

Comment: That's what source control is for. My advice is to just create the repository and forget about the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] is it possible to keep the history and the times when the files were created using Git and import them?

By default, `git commit` bakes the current system date into the resulting commit. However, you can override that behavior with the `--date` flag.

Therefore, you could

1. create a folder called `SABS_git` (for instance) and `cd` to it;
2. initialise a Git repo by running

   ```
   git init
   ```
3. copy `SABS v0.1b/sabs.sh` into `SABS_git/`.
4. stage `sabs.sh`, and commit with the desired date:

   ```
   git add sabs.sh
   git commit --date=<desired-date>
   ```

   where `<desired-date>` can be, for instance, `2014/01/01`.
5. write a descriptive commit message.
6. apply steps 3-5 to the next version of `sabs.sh` until exhaustion.

If you have many versions, you might want to write a shell file for automating some of those steps; you probably want to write a meaningful commit message each time, though, which cannot be automated.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for.  Would the only way to import this to github be to create a git repo then import it to github? Else, is there a way to run git commands on github?

Comment: @ChristopherStanley Cool, but this seems to be a different question altogether. See the GitHub help: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/.

Comment: When I do a git commit --date=2013/10/01 I get the following error: fatal: invalid date format: 2013/10/01

Comment: Works for me in Git 2.2.2. Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: Using Github for windows powershell - It is running Git 1.9.5 - When I changed the date to UNIX epoch format it seemed to work.